# Flutter download on ubuntu Error: 'cannot execute binary file: Exec format error'

Tags: bash, flutter, mobile, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to use Flutter on my ubuntu 18.04. Os-Type 32 bit. But I still become this error message 'cannot execute binary file: Exec format error'

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read carefully [System Requirements](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#system-requirements):

> To install and run Flutter, your development environment must meet these minimum requirements:
> Operating Systems: Linux (64-bit)
>
> ...

Linux 32-bit is not supported.